# retrieve multiple output from Matlab .net assembly in c#

Tags: c#, matlab

I am using a .NET assembly from Matlab in C# with multiple outputs, and I would like to retrieve the different outputs. 
However I get the following message: 
`cannot apply indexing with[] to an expression of type 'Mathworks.MATLAB:NET.Arrays.native.MWarray.'` when I try to retrieve the results from the MW array.

This is my code. I would like to ask for ideas on how to take out the results (result1, results2, etc...) from the MW array. Thank you in advance.

```
        Class1 matlabAdd = new Class1();

        MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWArray OutResult = null;
        OutResult = (MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWCellArray)matlabAdd.func_MYFUNC(input1, input2, input3, input4, input5);
        MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWCellArray result1 = (MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWCellArray) OutResult[1];
        MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWCellArray result2 = (MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWCellArray) OutResult[2];
        MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWCellArray result3 = (MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWCellArray) OutResult[3];
        MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWCellArray result4 = (MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWCellArray) OutResult[4];
        MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWCellArray result5 = (MathWorks.MATLAB.NET.Arrays.native.MWCellArray) OutResult[5];
        //double[,] result1 = ((double[,]) OutResult(1));

        DA.SetDataList(0, result1);
        DA.SetDataList(1, result2);
        DA.SetDataList(2, result3);
        DA.SetDataList(3, result4);
        DA.SetDataList(4, result5);
```